# Colour intersecting viewsheds by number of intersects

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, dem, viewshed

I'm creating a PyQGIS plugin which utilises the Grass7 `r.viewshed` algorithm. It creates viewsheds as `.tif` Layers in the project, using the main raster layer as a Digital Terrain/Elevation Model for elevation. You can see what these look like in QGIS below.
[image: Snippet of project, with viewsheds created, above the raster]
Currently the viewsheds that are generated, simply use the default singleband pallete colours.
For these layers that intersect, is there a way to set a specific colour for the areas where one or more viewsheds intersect?

For example:

- in areas that 2 viewsheds intersect, the colour would be red
- for 3 intersections, blue
- for 4 intersections, green

and so on.

One way to think of it would be as a rating of visibility in the areas covered by the viewsheds. The more viewsheds a point is in, the higher the rating would be and this would be shown by the colour.